# In ArcGIS Pro the attributes panel drop-down list of values seems to show symbology categories and not proper domain values

Tags: arcgis-pro, domains

In ArcGIS Pro I have a dataset that has mismatched values that were not entered using a domain, now I am fixing them but there is a lot of data and no easy find/replace patterns.

So I have been selecting records in the attribute window that need to be fixed and then opening the attribute pane to select the selected group and then bulk-change the value of the appropriate field, I do not want to do this with a field calculator because I want to make sure I am applying the proper coded value.

However, when I look at the values in the drop down menu within the attribute pane I think I am seeing the symbology values and not the proper domain values. See pic below, showing multiple records and the symbology values they are using:

[image]

Is there a way to have this attribute pane show the appropriate domain values for that field?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it....  there are two drop down menus, but the interface isn't so clear about that.  The rightmost one brings up a symbology based list but the drop down arrow to the left of it brings up the domain list:

[image: arrow points to domain drop down]